# Getting changes for a specific entity

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, dbcontext

Is there a more efficient way of doing the following?

```
public static DbEntityEntry<T> GetEntityChanges<T>(DbContext c, T entity) where T: class
{
    return c.ChangeTracker.Entries<T>().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Entity == entity);        
}
```

I have an entity, and I would like to get changes for that entity. Is there a way to get these without enumerating through *all* changed entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
public static DbEntityEntry<T> GetEntityChanges2<T>(DbContext c, T entity) where T: class
{
    return c.Entry(entity);
}
```

*Note: in practice, there is hardly a point wrapping it in a method, I'm doing this to stay consistent with the question*